# Cutting a cake n-times - expected number of pieces

Tags: expected-value

I'm trying to solve a brainteaser:

A 2D circle (cake) is cut randomly with straight lines n-times. What's the expected number of pieces?

Could you give me a hint on how to approach this? Is it possible to solve it analytically or by simulation?

Thanks!

Comment: As a start, find the probability that two lines cross

Comment: What is the probability distribution on the lines, i.e. how are the lines chosen?

Comment: While not the same problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability) illustrates how important it is to specify _how_ the lines are chosen. There are several different "uniform" distributions to choose from, and they presumably all yield different results.